# Creating a column that counts repeats in spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, count

I have this big dataframe, 7 million lines long, and I need to add a column that counts how many times a certain person (identified by and Integer) has come up before, like:

```
| Reg |   randomdata |                   
| 123 | yadayadayada |                 
| 246 | yedayedayeda |          
| 123 | yadeyadeyade |                 
|369  | adayeadayead |                
| 123 | yadyadyadyad |
```

to ->

```
| Reg |   randomdata |     count              
| 123 | yadayadayada |          1       
| 246 | yedayedayeda |          1  
| 123 | yadeyadeyade |          2      
| 369 | adayeadayead |          1      
| 123 | yadyadyadyad |          3
```

I already done a groupBy to know how many times each got repeated, but I need to get this count for a Machine learning exercise to get the probability of repetition according to how many times that happened before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following whereby we assume randomness can mean the same random value occurring and using spark sql with tempview, but can be done also with DF with select:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window._

case class xyz(k: Int, v: String)
val ds = Seq(
     xyz(1,"917799423934"),
     xyz(2,"019331224595"),
     xyz(3,"8981251522"),
     xyz(3,"8981251522"),
     xyz(4,"8981251522"),
     xyz(1,"8981251522"),
     xyz(1,"uuu4553")).toDS()

 ds.createOrReplaceTempView("XYZ")

spark.sql("""select z.k, z.v, dense_rank() over (partition by z.k order by z.seq) as seq from (select k,v, row_number() over (order by k) as seq from XYZ) z""").show
```

returning:

```
+---+------------+---+
|  k|           v|seq|
+---+------------+---+
|  1|917799423934|  1|
|  1|  8981251522|  2|
|  1|     uuu4553|  3|
|  2|019331224595|  1|
|  3|  8981251522|  1|
|  3|  8981251522|  2|
|  4|  8981251522|  1|
+---+------------+---+
```

Comment: I made some adaptations for multiple columns and that worked!
But I don't really understand much of what happened there, I should study more SQL to properly use dataframes then

Comment: Not so hard. Look at the query first without inline view and see what happens with this testset. Analytical functions are important. Success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 def countrds = udf((rds: Seq[String]) => {rds.length})
 val df2 = df1.groupBy(col("Reg")).agg(collect_list(col("randomdata")).alias("rds"))
                    .withColumn("count", countrds(col("rds")))
 df2.select('Reg', 'randomdata', 'count').show()
```